# How to change bundle identifier of already released app in Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to make some UI modification in my APP which include Firebase storage. So for the temporary purpose, I want to change bundle identifier in Firebase. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase doesn't allow to change the Bundle ID of existing application you can create a new one for the temporary basis.

Answer (score 1):

As of today you can´t change the bundle identifier in Firebase. The easiest solution is to create a new one.